# Background classes and custom theme don't work in Tailwind CSS with React

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am currently working on a project with ReactJS, Typescript and TailwindCSS and everything seems to be working properly. The point is, all TailwindCSS classes work just fine except the ones for the background. Whenever I use a class like,`bg-sky-500` or `bg-slate-500`, the color never displays and the background remains as it is. Also, I have tried to set a custom theme inside `tailwindcss.config.json`, but it didn't work either. Here are the configs used in the project:

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

**tailwind.config.ts**

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

**postcss.config.ts**

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    },
}
```

**main.ts**

```js
    const path = require("path");

    module.exports = {
       stories: ["../src/**/*.stories.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
       addons: [
          "@storybook/addon-links",
          "@storybook/addon-essentials",
          "@storybook/addon-interactions",
          "@storybook/preset-create-react-app",
       ],
       framework: "@storybook/react",
       core: {
         builder: "@storybook/builder-webpack5",
       },
       webpackFinal: async (config) => {
       config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\,css&/,
            use: [
                    {
                       loader: "postcss-loader",
                       options: {
                            ident: "postcss",
                            plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
                       },
                     },
                  ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
            });
            return config;
          },
        };
```

**preview.ts**

```js
    import "index.css";

    export const parameters = {
        actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
        controls: {
           matchers: {
              color: /(background|color)$/i,
              date: /Date$/,
           },
         },
     };
```

**index.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    @tailwind forms;
```

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: What version of Tailwind CSS are you using (see your `package.json` file)?

Comment: "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
 "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",

Answer (score 0):

The "sky" and "slate" colors only became available in Tailwind CSS version 3+. I would recommend upgrading to the latest for these colors and the many additional improvements.

If you are stuck with v2, you should reference the list of colors in the old documentation: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Alternatively, you can add these colors in your `tailwind.config.js` file in the `theme` section, copying the values from Tailwind 3+:

```js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        slate: {
          50: "rgb(248 250 252)",
          100: "rgb(241 245 249)",
          ...
        },
        sky: {
          50: "rgb(240 249 255)",
          100: "rgb(224 242 254)",
          ...
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

See: https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

Comment: So how can I upgrade to the last version knowing that I use it with the storybook?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Storybook. There are likely resources to find with a web search.